# React image source require not reading variables

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to dynamically render images through `props`.

When I hardcode the `img src`, I am able to render the image:

```
<img src={require('uploads/logo2-1537302321809.png')} />
```

When I try to render via the `props`

```
<img src={require(`${profile.image.URL}`)} />
```

I get an error:

**Error: Cannot find module 'uploads/logo2-1537302321809.png'.**

Comment: You cannot do that. You can declare variable with path to the image and use that in require

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const picture = 'picture.jpg';
<img src = {require(`./images/${picture}`)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do suppose [this](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/) should help you. The key point is that you're creating the separate component where you store all your images and call them whenever you need.

**Example:**

**"Images storage":**

```
    const images = {
    something: require(‘./path/image’)
};
export default Images;
```

**Importing:**

```
import Images from ‘whatever_you_name_this’;

<img source={Images.something} />
```

Comment: The issue I have with this is that the users will be uploading assets for their pages, so I don't know how many there will be or what they are named. I have the back end set up to pull in the proper URLs based on page and auth params.

Comment: @C.Red. probably you should use APIs then